# rxjava onStart event with delaySubscription

Tags: java, android, rx-java

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onStart();
        subscriber.onNext(1);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}).delaySubscription(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.e("TAG", String.format("(%s) - onCompleted", System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.e("TAG", String.format("(%s) - onError", System.currentTimeMillis()), e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
        Log.e("TAG", String.format("(%s) - onNext: %s", System.currentTimeMillis(), integer));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("TAG", String.format("(%s) - onStart", System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
});
```

output:

```
(1485004553817) - onStart
(1485004558818) - onNext: 1
(1485004558819) - onCompleted
```

why `onStart` event not waiting to `delaySubscription` and calling soon ?

i want aware when `call` method called

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says -

onStart -

> This method is invoked when the Subscriber and Observable have been connected but the Observable has not yet begun to emit items or send notifications to the Subscriber.

delaySubscription:

> Returns an Observable that delays the subscription to the source Observable by a given amount of time.

onNext is invoked only when the subscription is achieved. onStart is called the moment a connection is established. Thus, it works as expected according to the definition.

You can try commenting the code subscriber.onStart(); and execute the same again to notice that onStart is still called at the beginning. The intentional execution did not really invoke the said method because this was executed not on the real subscriber we created, but the one which was a result of delaySubscription (of type OnSubscribeDelaySubscription).

Below is a snippet which can probably help you achieve what you're looking for:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
      Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap(val -> {
          System.out.println("Initialize");
          return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
              System.out.println("onsubscribe");
              doMyAsyncStuff(subscriber);
          });
      }).subscribe(val -> System.out.println(val));

      Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().first();
   }
```

We initialize a `timer`, once timer is executed, we perform some task in `flatMap` which should be the same as what you earlier did with `onStart`. Once that task is executed, we emit a `Observable` which emits all the elements that you could have consumed earlier with `onNext` calls.

Comment: thanks but what is your solution to achieved to this ?

Comment: May be I can help if you can elaborate the use case. What do you want to execute in onStart and if you use onNext and onComplete?

Comment: i have a long operation in `call` method, i want show a progressbar when long operation started.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a code snippet which probably might help you. Please take a look.

Comment: thanks. but "Initialize" is calling in background thread, i want in UI thread (android)

Comment: Not exactly unsure about that part, but have tried to depict using `create` method where you can pass on the subscriber to background thread to trigger a call when async stuff is complete. `create` can be used even in the first part where I have used `Observable.timer` method.